# Find third highest salary of employee without order by and limit

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Find third highest salary of employee without order by and limit.

```
 select(SELECT MIN(Salary)
    FROM   (SELECT * TOP (3) Salary
           FROM   Employees
           )
```

Not working in the mysql work bench

Comment: This query won't work in MySQL Workbench because `TOP` is not supported by MySQL. It's part of SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
SELECT salary 
FROM Employees e1
WHERE 3-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM Employees e2
WHERE e2.salary > e1.salary)
```

Comment: yes working , please explain what is 3-1?

Comment: WHERE N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary), for 2nd highest, N = 3, for 3rd  highest N = 3... and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sql
WITH emp (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) rowId, * 
    FROM employee
) 
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE rowId = 3;
```

Comment: can't use order by in the query